# Erro ao converter 'MimeKit.MimePart' no tipo 'MimeKit.TextPart'

Tags: c#, mime-type

Lendo emails de xml tentando enviar pra um objeto XmlDocument tento converter o arquivo anexo em uma string para ler dentro do LoadXML, porém em alguns casos está dando o erro

> Não é possivel converter um objeto do tipo 'MimeKit.MimePart' no tipo
> 'MimeKit.TextPart'.

segue o código:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    String str = ((MimeKit.TextPart)anexo).Text; //aqui está o xml string.(e Aqui que dá o erro)


    xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
```

segue abaixo o xml do email e o que foi lido: Sem diferenças entre eles.
no caso nao houve o cast pra MimeKit.TextPart;

[Diff dos xmls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NKbv.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente alguns emails estão vindo com o anexo no formato "texto" e outros estão vindo no formato "binário".

Se você pegar o conteúdo original da mensagem de email, vai notar que o anexo pode vir de duas formas diferentes, por exemplo:

[Exemplo de email com anexo vindo como "Content-Type: text/xml"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztWp8.png)

[Exemplo de email com anexo vindo como "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj0Ta.png)

Da forma que você está lendo o código só funciona corretamente para a primeira situação e acontece o erro que você reportou ao passar pela segunda situação.

Em vez de tentar converter pra `TextPart`, você pode manter como um `MimePart` e ler diretamente o conteúdo como stream, por exemplo:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    var part = (MimePart)anexo;
    part.Content.DecodeTo(memory); // carrega o conteúdo para a memória e já converte automaticamente quando é base64
    memory.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory, Encoding.UTF8)) // lê com a codificação UTF-8 para não ter problemas com acentuação
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o código funciona para as duas situações.